# NSURLConnectionDelegate For Authentication Challenge won't get called on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, https, aes, rsa

i am using `NSURLConnection` to connect with `https` api and server is using

```
"Go Daddy Certificate Authority - G2" and "is encrypted using a modern cipher suite.

The connection uses TLS 1.2.

The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and uses ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism."
```

And i had implemented following delegates

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
 [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

But the problem is "None of the delegate methods is hitting". Why Authentication method is not hitting and how to fix it?

In Implemetation file is useed as follows `@interface classname () < NSURLConnectionDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate >`

And NSURLConnection Delegate directly hits following method `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

NSURLConnection Code is as follows

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlString"];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"v1.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Version"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    DLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@", request, request.allHTTPHeaderFields, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    // send the login request
    self.loginConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [self.loginConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                                    forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.loginConnection start];
```

Comment: your xcode version is Xcode 7 ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, xcode version is 6.4

Answer (score 0):

This happened  when  updating iOS 7 app to iOS 8. We were using Oracle SOA as the middle ware and sunddenly it stopped calling the delegate methods. Below will work for both iOS8 and iOS7.

```
 - (void) addBasicHTTPAuthenticationHeaders
        {
            NSString * wsUserName = @"userNameForWebService";
            NSString * wsPassword = @"passwordForWebService";

            NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", wsUserName, wsPassword];
            NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn]];
            [urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        }
```

**OR**

For iOS 8 and above, you must implement `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`. `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` is not called in iOS8, only in older operating systems.

So, to provide authentication in iOS8 and above, implement the method above and in there you must invoke one of the challenge-responder methods (NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender` protocol):

```
useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:

continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: 

cancelAuthenticationChallenge:

performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChalleng:
```

`rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge`:
`didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` is a method on `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, whilst the rest of your methods (except `didFailWithError`) are all `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. Are you implementing both protocols in your controller? It would perhaps help if you posted all your class' code.

Comment: I had edited "NSURLConnection" starts as above but still it doesn't hit Authentication method and directly hits didReceiveResponse method. I had edited the question.

Comment: you need to see this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Deprecated methods used because app supports ios7 also

Comment: yes you right so you currently running it in iOS 7 simulator ?

Comment: Currently running in iPhone 4S - OS Version 8.1.2

Comment: You using iOS 8.1.2 then how can it will supports ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91848/discussion-between-sakthimuthiah-and-piyush-patel).